# Change KexAlgorithms on OpenSSH

Tags: openssh, diffie-hellman, sshd

I would like to disable 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1' and 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1' key exchange algorithms on my OpenSSH.
I edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config and added this line:
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

After this I restarted SSH by command -> 'service sshd restart'

Now, when I run command 'ssh -Q kex', the output is still:
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
curve25519-sha256
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
gss-gex-sha1-
gss-group1-sha1-
gss-group14-sha1-

Why didn't do any changes? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se], [sf], or [su].

Answer (score -1):

I believe "ssh -Q kex" shows all Key Exchange Algorithms that are available: not necessarily just that algorithms that are configured for use in any given situation.  Consider, in ssh_config, one can designate a specific set of Key Exchange Algorithms to be used with a particular host.  How would "ssh -Q kex" know which host is of interest?  Also, I have configured /etc/ssh/ssh_config, ~/.ssh/config, or even /etc/ssh/sshd_config, to specify that certain Key Exchange Algorithms be enabled or disabled.  In my experience, "ssh -Q kex" does not reflect the changes.

I have had better luck by actually attempting to log into a specific ssh host/server using ssh -vv or ssh -vvv, and then reviewing what my client and the server are each offering for use in key exchange.  After configuring the appropriate config file or after adding "-o kex=specific_key_exchange_algorithm" to the ssh command line, I do see the changes reflected in "debug" messages reported.  YMMV.  I hope this helps someone even if the answer is rather late with respect to the original poster's question.

Answer (score -1):

`ssh` shows keys used by SSH Client on the machine, and `sshd` shows keys used by SSH Server on the machine.

You have modified the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that is leveraged by `sshd`.

Try using `sshd -T`.